# How to assign options to a variable?

Tags: python, bash, optparse

I'm new to python and programming in general. I want to assign options to a variable by using optparse module in ipython. My code is as follows:

```
import sys
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-v', action="store_true", dest='verbose', default=False)
(options, others) = parser.parse_args()
print options.verbose
if options.verbose:
    print "Not yet"
else:
    print "Done"
```

I saved them in a file and I can run it in bash like this:

```
$ python filename.py -verbose
```

Now I want to assign the whole code to a variable. I hope it can be run like this:

```
$ myvar -verbose
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: So you just  want myvar to be a python binary?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to make your python script executable with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Add this as the first line in your filename.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Next you need to change the file permissions to be executable. At the command line, execute:

```
$ chmod +x filename.py
```

Then you can execute filename.py directly:

```
$ ./filename.py -verbose
```

You could of course rename filename.py to myvar, or make a [symolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) like this:

```
$ ln -s filename.py myvar
```

Now you can do:

```
$ ./myvar -verbose
```

If you don't want to add the `/.` (which just tells the shell that the executable is in the current directory), or want to be able to use the "myvar" command line from anywhere, you could add your working directory to the environment `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD
```

You might want to read a good tutorial on command line usage for more on this sort of thing. A little time invested can be really rewarding!

Comment: I agree with everything here with the exception of adding `$PWD` to the search path. There's a reason (security) the local directory isn't just checked before resorting to path lookup. Just use `./myvar`.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are your friend:

```
alias myvar="python filename.py"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just assign to the shell variable:

```
myvar='python filename.py'
$myvar -verbose
```

Note the leading `$`, which would not be required if you used an alias (@Nick Edward's solution).

By the way, `-verbose` will set options v, e, r, b, o, s, and e.  Maybe you mean a long option, like `--verbose`?